# Links in bootstrap grid stop working in small screen mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is required to make links in bootstrap grids work throughout all the media breakpoints ?

In my case, the links work only as long as the grid is not stacked.

This is what the grid looks like:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="room" style="height: 155.60px; width: calc(25.0% - 4px);"> <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>This is another row</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The working fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pTw2j/8/

**Edit** Thanks for the fast answer. I chose `overflow:hidden;` at the end to avoid scrollbars while still fixing the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the links are floated, resulting in a height of 0 for the parent `.storey` container.

Setting `overflow: auto` on the container will fix the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/pTw2j/13/

```
.storey {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This is referred to as "clearfixing." If you're interested in learning more, here are two good articles:

[CSS Tricks: Force Element to Self-Clear its Children](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

[David Walsh: CSS Clear Fix](http://davidwalsh.name/css-clear-fix)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case a better solution was to add the class of "clearfix" to the containing div. Bootstrap has this class built in so you don't have to do anything with your CSS.

Comment: For reference, see [Understanding Bootstrap's clearfix class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973317/understanding-bootstraps-clearfix-class).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:auto` will result in a horizontal scroll bar. Best to use `clearfix` class which resolves the issue.