# Link isn't clickable within my navbar on Bootstrap 2 page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone suggest why the first link isn't clickable & link to the index page within my header on my site using Bootstrap 2 - the link with the 'brand' class currently isn't clickable nor does it link to homepage

Any advice on how to fix?

```
<div class="navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
 <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="brand" href="/"><img src="/images/logo.png" id="logo"></a>
   <a class="btn btn-navbar btn-warning navbar-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </a>
<!-- extra html content below this line... -->
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, could you provide a demo of any kind (fiddle or something else)?

Comment: demo or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the clearfix class which made the navbar container sit on the top of your image.

After removing **clearifx** from this line of code:

`<div class="nav-collapse collapse clearfix" id="navbar-collapse-main">`

it's OK. You just might need to reposition the logo slightly.

[More about clearfix class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973317/understanding-bootstraps-clearfix-function)